# How can I remove border from img tag?

Tags: html, css

I want to remove this border. This creating ugly appearance when images loading. Specially in big images.

[image]

```css
img {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<img src="kansdkans" />
```

Comment: You're only getting that border because the image wasn't found?

Comment: There is no border around the image. The image not found image has a grey line as part of it. Don't link to URLs which aren't images.

Comment: Yeah. that's the problem already. beacuse I'm using lazy loading.

Comment: You can add a class to all the images that was not loaded yet and set `visibility:hidden;` to that class, and once the image is loaded, remove that class to make it visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use alt element for remove that border.

```
<img src="kansdkans" alt="My Image Here" />
```

Comment: hai @dgknca  is this answer helps you. please mark as correct.